# How to initialize the Vue app depending on back-end response first?

Tags: api, vue.js, vuex, settings, guard

I want some code to be ran before anything else in the app, that code will send a request to the Back-end and then update the store.
I need that part to be executed first because route guards depend on it, how to achieve that?

### Code Example

**Fetching user information & settings**

```js
async init() {
    await AuthService.initCSRF();
    await AuthService.getUser().then((res) => {
      if (res.data && res.data.user) {
        this.loginLocally(res.data.user);
      } else {
        this.logoutLocally();
      }
    });
}
```

**Auth guard**

```
export function isLoggedIn(to, from, next) {
  console.log('Checked', store.state.auth.isLoggedIn);
  if (store.state.auth.isLoggedIn) {
    next();
    return;
  }

  next({ name: 'login' })
}
```

Comment: What does depend on init process exactly? You could wait for it before calling app mount(). The problem is that the router may not wait for the app to be mounted and starts immediately. If it's auth guard that depends on initialization, you need to wait for init promise in router.beforeEach

Comment: I only want to execute it once, and I also want the routes to wait while that is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in my old project, I did something like this. hope you get some idea.

**app.js**

```
import App from './components/App.vue'
store.dispatch('auth/attempt', sessionStorage.getItem('token')).then(() =>{
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    store,
    render: h => h(App),
 });
});
```

here I'm validating the token saved in local storage before rendering the app.

my Vuex actions something like this

```
async signIn({dispatch}, credentials) {
  let response = await axios.post("auth/signin", credentials);
  await dispatch('attempt', response.data.token)
},


async attempt({commit, state}, token) {
  if (token) {
    await commit('SET_TOKEN', token);

  }
  if (!state.token) {
    return;
  }

  try {
    let response = await axios.get('auth/me');
    commit('SET_USER', response.data)
  } catch (e) {
    commit('SET_TOKEN', null);
    commit('SET_USER', null);
  }
},
async signOut({commit}) {
  axios.post('auth/signout').then(() => {
    commit('SET_TOKEN', null);
    commit('SET_USER', null);
  });
}
```

I'm using a  subscriber to listen to mutations and add or remove token in request headers

```
import store from '../store'

store.subscribe((mutation) => {

 if (mutation.type === 'auth/SET_TOKEN') {
  if (mutation.payload) {
   axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${mutation.payload}`;
  sessionStorage.setItem('token', mutation.payload);
} else {
  axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = null;
  sessionStorage.removeItem('token');
  }
 }
});
```

Finally an axios interceptor for handle token expiration.

```
import router from '../plugins/router'
import store from '../store'
import axios from "axios";

axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {

  return response;
}, (error) => {
if (error.response.status) {
  if (error.response.status === 401) {

  if (router.currentRoute.name !== 'landing') {
    store.dispatch('auth/clearToken').then(() => {
      router.replace({
        name: 'landing'
      });

    }).finally(() => {
      swal.fire(
        'Your Session is Expired',
        'Please sign in again!',
        'error'
      )
    });
    }
  }
}

return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialization promise can be waited before calling `.mount(...)`. The problem is that Vue router starts [separately from the application](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1377) and won't be delayed this way.

If it's the router that depends on initialization process, a way to delay router start is to wait for the promise in router hook that is triggered before other ones:

```
const initPromise = init();

...

router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  await initPromise;
  next();
});
```

Comment: But that way the `initPromise` will be execute every time the user go to another route, right? How can I execute it only one time?

Comment: Promises aren't executed. They are waited. If you call init() outside beforeEach once, it will be called once