# Is that a safe way to initialize my Vue app?

Tags: vue.js, authentication, vuex

I want some code to be executed to fetch user info/settings before the app reaches to routing guards, because the guards depends on the state that will be updated when I fetch user settings.

I do it that way, is it safe? is there a better alternative?

```
store.dispatch("appInit").finally(() => {
  const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { 'app': App },
    router,
    store,
  })
})
```

Comment: "before the app reaches to routing guards" - this has already been addressed in your previous question. Vue router initial navigation isn't tied to app init. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70547863/3731501 . So no, it's not safe and yes, there are better alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a great way to do it, with one possible change.

If your application depends on error-free initialization, instead of using `finally`, you should to use `then` and also have a `catch` block that handles any errors that occur during initialization.

The way you have it now, if the initialization fails, it will still try to load the app.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I don't mind that. I just need to know users' settings before doing any route guarding. I have in the app other parts where I'm handling the errors.